# SSRS expression - If null value then return 0 instead of blank

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I've seen a few examples but I just can't figure it out for my case.
My expressions sums all values from field `Total` from the dataset `AutoDeliveryCount`. I need to reference the dataset since I'm using a few `Total` fields in my report. If the stored procedure returns null, how can I have my expression return 0 instead of a blank?

```
=Sum(Fields!Total.Value, "AutoDeliveryCount")
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Sum(Fields!Total.Value, "AutoDeliveryCount"))=True, 0, Sum(Fields!Total.Value, "AutoDeliveryCount"))
```

Comment: does this cause SSRS to evaluate the SUM() twice?

Comment: [IsNothing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.information.isnothing?view=net-5.0) returns Boolean. Thus, there is no need compare it with True. `=IIf(IsNothing(Sum(Fields!Total.Value, "AutoDeliveryCount")), 0, Sum(Fields!Total.Value, "AutoDeliveryCount"))`

Answer (score 20):

Simply:

```
=Sum(Fields!Total.Value, "AutoDeliveryCount") + 0
```

Comment: This the real MVP. Forget adding yet another annoying nested IIF wrapping around everything... just throw + 0 at the end. Brilliant.

Comment: Yep, less verbose and equally functional.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to show 0 in integer column. Write Round(Fields!yourfield.Value ,2) to display as 0.00 . If your field is returning empty.

Answer (score 1):

From the marked solution:
`=IIf(IsNothing(Sum(Fields!Total.Value, "AutoDeliveryCount"))=True, 0, Sum(Fields!Total.Value, "AutoDeliveryCount"))`

1. IsNothing() always returns true or false and also IIF() always delivers true or false. So "=True" is redundant.
   `IIf(IsNothing(Sum(Fields!Total.Value, "AutoDeliveryCount")), 0, ...`
   works exactly the same way.
2. What if `Sum(Fields!Total.Value, "AutoDeliveryCount")` returns 0? Since IsNothing() and 0 are being treated the same way 0 will be returned in both cases. It does not make any difference whether a field is empty or does contain the nubmer 0. How would you handle the difference between 0 and nothing?

Answer (score 0):

Another option may be to use the **Format** property for the cell concerned. For example if you are displaying an Integer you could format it as:

```
#,##0
```

This will display 0 if the value is null/empty.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Which SSRS version supports this?

Comment: @Rashmi - SQL Server 2012. I developed the report using Visual Studio 2013 Update 5 with Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2013 installed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this formula in 2017 and it worked for me:

```
=IIF(Sum(Fields!Total.Value)=Nothing, 0, Sum(Fields!Total.Value, "AutoDeliveryCount"))
```